# Half-integer dimension of a complex tangent space?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-manifolds

In Nakahara's GTaP chapter 8.2, he explains the *almost complex structure* on a real manifold of even dimension. I'm a bit confused by the dimension equation that immediately follows equation (8.27):

$$
\text{dim}_\mathbb C T_pM^+=\text{dim}_\mathbb C T_pM^-=\frac 12\text{dim}_\mathbb C T_pM^\mathbb C=\frac 12\text{dim}_\mathbb C M
$$

$T_pM^+$ is the subspace of holomorphic vectors (those which transform as $J(Z)=iJ(Z)$ under the complex structure $J$).

The simplest example of a complex manifold is $M=\mathbb C$, and we have $\text{dim}_\mathbb C\mathbb C=1$. In this case, the expressions in this equation would have the value $\frac 12$.

How can the dimension of a vector space be half-integer? What am I mising?

I cannot find any indication that the complex dimension of $M$ must be even.

Comment: Might be it is $\mathbb R$ instead of $\mathbb C$ in the last two terms?

Comment: It's not listed in the errata list. $T_pM^+$ and $T_pM^-$ have the bases $\frac\partial{\partial z}$ and $\frac\partial{\partial \bar z}$. Are they $\mathbb C$-linearly independent? If they are, then the complex dimension must be even.

Comment: @JohnMa forgot to @ you

Comment: The last $\tfrac{1}{2}$ is a typo. In fact, using $\operatorname{dim}(A\otimes B)=\operatorname{dim}(A)\cdot\operatorname{dim}(B)$, we see that $\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{R}(T_pM^\mathbb{C})=\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{R}(T_p M\otimes \mathbb{C})=2n\cdot 2=4n$, implying $\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{C}T_pM^\mathbb{C}$ is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A,B$ be vector spaces over $K$, then $$\operatorname{dim}(A\otimes_K B)=\operatorname{dim}A\cdot\operatorname{dim}B.$$
So, if $M$ is a $2n$-dimensional, then $\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{R}T_pM=2n$. Now, the tangent space Nakahara is talking about is the *complexified* tangent space, $T_pM^\mathbb{C}:=T_pM\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$. The real dimension of this space is $\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{R} T_pM^\mathbb{C}=\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{R}T_pM\cdot\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}=4n$. Using $\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{C}=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{R}$, we see that $\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{C}T_pM^\mathbb{C}=2\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{C}M=2n.$ The last $1/2$ in your text is a typo.